# unbalanced mixed-effect model (2 measures)

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I am planning a study where participants perform a task lasting, say, 100 to 300 secs; its length is randomly drawn from a uniform distribution with increments of 1 sec. Is this appropriate or would it be better with fewer groups, e.g. 100 secs, 120 secs, etc. I am interested in how time after the task and the length of the task influence their response. I want to measure their response directly after (time 0) and after a delay of 1 to, say, 14 days. That is, there are only 2 measures for each participant (one at time 0 and one at a later random time). Is a random coefficients model appropriate, having only two measurements per participants.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How many participants ?

Comment: I imagine that I would need 1,000 or maybe more

Comment: So each participant performs a task at t0 which lasts for some period (a few minutes) and you measure a response. Then they perform the same task (for the same period as the first time they performed it ?) at a future time that can be anything from 1 - 14 days later and you measure their response again. Your central research question concerns the association of the response with the length of the task and the time between tasks. Is this correct ? Please can you tell us more about the tasks and the responses and any other variables that you measure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. They perform the task only once. Directly after the experience, they state the amount of dollars they would need to repeat it. Then, sometime between 1 and 14 days after, they, again, have to state how much they would want for repeating it. Second time, I actually draw a random number to determine if they should repeat and be paid extra; first time, they are informed that it is not necessary to repeat today.